# How do I get a hook on an XML files root node using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML file (below) and i'd like to get a hook on the name of the root node.

I've tried the following:

```
$config = simplexml_load_string($xml_data);
echo $config->getName();
```

Which echo's nothing. I've also iterated over the result but it starts at the children of the root node

```
foreach($config as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key;
}
// echo's ReturnStatus, SearchURL and PropertyResults
```

I just want the name of the root node "SearchResponse". I can't seem to find anything in the SimpleXMLElement class documentation that'll help http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<SearchResponse>
  <ReturnStatus>
    <Success>
        <data>true</data>
        <data2>true</data2>
    </Success>
    <Success>
        <data>false</data>
        <data2>true</data2>
    </Success>
    <Exception />
  </ReturnStatus>
  <SearchURL />
  <PropertyResults>
    <PropertyResult>
      <PropertyID>1468830</PropertyID>
      <PropertyName>Sands Acapulco</PropertyName>
    </PropertyResult>
    <PropertyResult>
      <PropertyID>1353302</PropertyID>
      <PropertyName>Acapulco Turquesa</PropertyName>
    </PropertyResult>
    <PropertyResult>
      <PropertyID>4521565</PropertyID>
      <PropertyName>Almaria Delsonto</PropertyName>
    </PropertyResult>   
  </PropertyResults>
</SearchResponse>
```

Comment: Your code [works for me](http://codepad.org/ggvVydOF)...

Comment: Yep your right, this does work, one thing I forgot to include was the Zend_Config_Xml abstraction I was using. That seems to restrict you from being able to access the root node. I'll ditch it and stick with native PHP. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does work:

```
$config = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $config->getName();
```

Tested with the XML you provided, Output:

```
SearchResponse
```

You write it would not work, so probably the issue is not the API.